# How do i update heroku environment variables from a node.js script?

Tags: heroku

I am using heroku environment variables to store oauth2 tokens for authentication with a webhook i've created. As these tokens update, i need to update the environment variables from within the script after i retrieve them.

I've tried the code below, but when i run 'heroku config' from CLI, the old tokens show up.

`process.env.GOOGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN = JSON.parse(body).access_token;`

Comment: Why would you store OAuth tokens in environment variables?

Comment: Hi Chris, i need to store the refresh token for when my access_token expires. Since the script is accessed via webrequest with some POST body i can't force the user through re-authentication. The service doesn't offer an API key. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: ...right, but why _in environment variables_? Are you talking about per-user tokens? Shouldn't those be stored client-side?

Comment: Hey Chris thank you for taking the time. Indeed it's the user side, but i am the user in this case, making a call to the webhook. It's about the google people api, i need to create a new contact via rest request and only way of auth is oauth2. There is a section on API key, but they don't supply one via the console as offered. https://developers.google.com/people/v1/how-tos/authorizing

Regarding storage, i could store them on 'user' side, but i don't really have a place for that, using a SAAS app (globiflow) to make the request.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so i figured it out. Just posting here for reference. You can update heroku environment variables using the heroku API. You can get a key via CLI using `heroku authorization:create`, and then use that API KEY in a patch call to heroku. More info on how to: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#config-vars